# Implement role based access control with IdentityServer4 and .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

We have an existing database, and need to implement role based access control with IdentityServer4 and .NET Core.

My question is that:

1 Does IdenityServer4 support RBAC? e.g. Is it via scope claim? How should it be implemented?

2 Can I use the existing database? Or Must I create a new database?

Any advice or code sample would be appreciated.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/Quickstarts/7_EntityFrameworkStorage

**Update**

We implement Resource Owner Passowrd grant type and RBAC.

Any advice or links to code sample would be appreciated.

Comment: You can see https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1786 for how to involve the role claim in both server(IDS4) and client(MVC) side .

Comment: Roles are not part of IdentityServer but part of Identity in general. And from what I've read they are moving away from the AspNetRoles tables. The alternative is to use 'role' claims. When setting up the configuration of the IdentityServer client/api you can map to the claims that represent the roles.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Can you elaborate on the 'role' claims or links to code sample. "When setting up the configuration of the IdentityServer client/api you can map to the claims that represent the roles"

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/f44fd63d0508322c57c81435fccaebe1a68e9cf9/Clients/src/MvcHybrid/Startup.cs#L65 This will map claims of type 'role' as a role (which can be used with IsInRole, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

On Identity Server side , you can create [Profile Service](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html) to make IDS4 include `role` claim when issuing tokens .

If example , if using ASP.NET Identity to mange users/roles , you can create profile service like :

```
public class MyProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public MyProfileService()
    { }

    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var roleClaims = context.Subject.FindAll(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
        List<string> list = context.RequestedClaimTypes.ToList();
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(roleClaims);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        // await base.IsActiveAsync(context);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And register in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<IProfileService, MyProfileService>();
```

On client side , you should map the role claim from your JWT Token and try below config in `AddOpenIdConnect` middleware :

```
  options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
  options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
```