# ASP.NET Identity in MVC client using IdentityServer causes loop

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an Asp.NET Core application that uses IdentityServer for authentication. 
 This works fine. 
Now I want to use ASP.NET Core Identity in my application for managing roles, claims, etc.

The documentation saysI should add `service.AddIdentity ...` for that. 
However, when I add that in my client to the Startup.cs, the login with IdentityServer no longer works.

I will be redirected to IdentityServer, login and redirected back to the client (this works fine) 
However, then my client throws an error about authorization and redirects to the IdentityServer again. This causes an endless loop

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:44331/signin-oidc application/x-www-form-urlencoded 5297
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 184.9938ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44331/  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: Identity.Application was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home", page = "", area = ""}. Executing action TestApplication.Controllers.HomeController.Index (TestApplication)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: oidc was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action TestApplication.Controllers.HomeController.Index (TestApplication) in 15.4912ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 29.286ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:44331/signin-oidc application/x-www-form-urlencoded 5297
-- and it starts all over again
```

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();            
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddTransient<ApiService>();
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;                       
        });


        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = 'Cookies';
            options.UseTokenLifetime = true; 

            options.Authority = 'https://localhost:44350; 
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

            options.ClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer:ClientId");
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer:ClientSecret");
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token token"

            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.Scope.Add("api1");                
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("email");

            options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";

        });

        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                             .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                             .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)
            .AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "areas",
               template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: You have to configure ASP.NET Identity in your identity server, not in your MVC app. The users will login there (Id Server), which can manage the roles as well, and return them as claims. In your MVC app you just add normal  `Policies` to apply authorization in your endpoints depending on roles.

Comment: Checkout this sample project: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html

Comment: So you're saying that all user management etc should now be done in IdentityServer? hm, that's annoying.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can hook ASP.Identity to it.. meaning it will read from that db and authenticate users giving you back an acess token with the users claims (roles). You could use the other app to manage the “Identity” db if you’d like.

Comment: Yeah, I have ASP.Identity in my IdentityServer. I'm trying to find a way to use and extend IdentityUser in my client app without breaking the login mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

On Identity Server side , you can create Profile Service to make IDS4 include role claim when issuing tokens . Then on client side you can  map the role claim from your JWT Token to your claim principle . You can refer to  code sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54685031/5751404) .

To manage users or roles , you can provide API endpoint in your identity server4 application , or create a new application as another resource to manage your database , you client application will acquire access token for accessing you new application form Identity Server 4 , send request by appending token to HTTP Authorization header for management API calls .

Comment: Basically exactly what I've said in my comments :)

Comment: @jpgrassi Yes,  also provide a code sample for how to map roles with asp.net identity in IDS4 :)

Comment: There’s already samples for identity on IdentityServer GitHub repo, and they probably map roles to claims there. Just to be clear, I was not trying to diminish or be sarcastic to your answer. Was just stating the fact because it looked like OP was not being able to connect my thoughts on his solution.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this and still wants to authenticate via IdSrv but manage users outside of IdSrv, replace this:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

in your client app with this

```
services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    //.AddDefaultUI() // use standard identity UI forms for register, forgot pass etc.
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Uncomment the line above to use the standard UI forms from MS identity but beware that you'll have to override the default sign in logic afterwards. This is done by adding the identity scaffolding to your project.